# Why does GMP use a pointer at the end of struct instead of zero sized array or Flexible Array Member?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, biginteger, flexible-array-member

Most of the sites I've been reading state that a zero-sized array, single element array or Flexible Array Members is the way to go when a dynamic array is needed, but the definition of an integer in GMP's source code is a pointer at the end of the struct (__mpz_struct), why is that?

I was expecting it to use zero-sized arrays, single element arrays or FAM

Comment: GMP uses the struct to control the size of the number, similar to a dynamic array that one would write with count, capacity, pointer. This is `__mpz_struct`. But, this is semi-hidden. One uses `mpz_t`: `typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];` so one can pass around what looks like numbers "passed by value" when, in fact, we're passing around pointers.

Comment: *Most of the sites I've been reading state that a zero-sized array, single element array or Flexible Array Members is the way to go when a dynamic array is needed* - this is quite arguable. Zero-size array is non-standard and along with the single-element array are kind of "hack" to emulate FAM. FAM itself is quite confusing for many developers and has limitations (like having only one per struct and it must be the last element). Using a pointer to dynamic substructure is a natural choice if one doesn't want to deal with the above.

Comment: Predates the addition of FAMs to the language and didn't want to use old compiler extensions like a 0 length array?

Comment: Further, `__mpz_struct` has `mp_limb_t *` which is where the variable length data is stored. `mp_limb_t` can be uint32_t or uint64_t (or even uint16_t). This depends upon what the "natural" register/integer size is for the processor we're building for (e.g.): uint16_t for 8086, uint32_t for i386, uint64_t for x86_64. This is something that the lib worries about so we don't have to.

Comment: I must be old (sigh) ... What's a "FAM"?

Comment: @CraigEstey Flexible Array Member

Comment: Just redid my websearch. Okay, `int data[];` as the last element of the struct. No, it _can't_ be used in GMP because the library _must_ be able to grow/shrink the array _at will_. For example, if we use GMP to iterate factorials from 1 to N, we start with just one limb but grow to thousands (or millions) _as needed_. FAM can't do this for GMP.

Comment: Those 3 constructs (zero-sized array, single-element array or FAM) are placed at the end of the struct, I wasn't expecting GMP to use a pointer.

Comment: @deltakid0, it is *much* more common to store a pointer to dynamically allocated space inside a `struct` than it is to use a FAM or FAM-analogue.  There are various reasons for this, some technical, some cultural, some personal.

Comment: @CraigEstey a quick search answers _A flexible array member is a C99 feature and can be used to access a variable-length object._ isn't a dynamic array a variable-length object?

Comment: @deltakid0, that description is a bit misleading and a lot oversimplified.

Comment: When growing the data in a struct with FAM, the pointer to the _struct_ has to change. This doesn't work. Consider the signature: `void mpz_add(mpz_t ret,mpz_t op1,mpz_t op2);` A user of this (pseudo code init): `mpz_t z = 1, x = 37, y = 13783739530823829810238239872238238239238923;`. Now, `mpz_add(z,x,y);` The `z` array must _grow_. With FAM, the _caller's_ pointer would have to change. Caller's pointer would become _stale_ with FAM.

Comment: BTW, before FAM (circa 1980), we did: (1) `struct dynarray { int count; int array[1]; };` But, this is a cute [and degenerate] case of: (2) `struct dynarray { int count; int *array; };` The former with the FAM precursor was mostly used to have a dynamic array with a _single_ `malloc` call (vs. two for (2)). This trick was used on systems with limited memory and to reduce fragmentation. But, with (1), you can't change the array size unless the caller knows you're doing it. Instead of the above, we'd need: `z = mpz_add(z,x,y);` with FAM. Or, `mpz_add(&z,x,y);`

Comment: Not answering my question yet.